# Sampling rate 44.1khz for buzzer

Tags: shell, text-processing

How can I set sampling rate of 44.1khz for my buzzer in the following code?

```
_alarm() {   ( \speaker-test --frequency $1 --test sine )&   pid=$!;   \
               \sleep 0.${2}s;   \kill -9 $pid; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code is a shell **function** that needs 2 arguments to be called, marked by `$1` and `$2`. The man page of `speaker-test` yields:

```
-f | --frequency FREQ
       sine wave of FREQ Hz
```

So the first argument is the frequency, in *Hertz*. The second is the decimal part of the number of seconds for the `sleep` invocation, before the `kill` is executed and stops the beeping. So if you want 44.1kHz for 0.5 s for example :

```
_alarm 44100 5
```

Should do the trick!